# How do you align input texts?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make a form with a username, password and an email. But for some reason the input text or the box for email isn't aligned with the boxes for the username and the password. I was wondering if there's a way to make them all align each other.

```
<form>
   <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="30"><br><br>
   <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
   <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="30">
    <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

It's just for the sake of making everything look nice and pretty.

Comment: Could you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Always fiddle and fiddle... Give us css!

Comment: I guess, he don't have css - http://jsfiddle.net/9y352pn6/1/

Comment: @noob1234 It looks pretty good - [TRY THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/9y352pn6/3/) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>
      <table>
           <tr> <td> <label for="username">Username</label> </td> <td> <input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="30"> </td> </tr>
           <tr> <td> <label for="password">Password</label> </td> <td> <input type="password" id="password" name="password"></td> </tr>
           <tr> <td>  <label for="email">Email</label> </td> <td><input type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="30"></td> </tr>
           <tr> <td></td> <td> <input type="submit" value="Register"> </td> </tr>
       </table>
</form>
```

should work, just surroundet it with a table.

Answer (score 1):

Oh man... Tables?? HTML from '90s incoming!

```
<style>
label {
    width: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<form>
   <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="30"><br><br>
   <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
   <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="30">
    <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: Haha exactly! `90s incoming.

Answer (score 1):

**I went for a different approach than a table, since if your are going to table up your form, I suggest you use a solid css framework, which is simply better.**

This is the approach of CSS only **[A Cool Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84oeo9bn/)**

```
form {
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

label, input {
    /* in order to define widths */
    display: inline-block;
}

label {
    width: 30%;
    /* positions the label text beside the input */
    text-align: right;
}

label + input {
    width: 30%;
    /* large margin-right to force the next element to the new-line
       and margin-left to create a gutter between the label and input */
    margin: 0 30% 0 4%;
}

/* only the submit button is matched by this selector,
   but to be sure you could use an id or class for that button */
input + input {
    float: right;
}

input[type="submit"]{
 margin: 4% 40%;  

}
```

With all that said, I also suggest you change the old way of forms being written with label values to placeholder.

for more reference **[Placeholders are cool!](http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)**

Comment: I have feeling that you'll be lynched for w3schools :D There are some fanatics here. http://w3fools.com

Comment: Well placeholders aren't that much of a complex. I would never send him there to learn, only to view the concept of placeholders. :D cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<form>
<tr>
  <td> <label for="username">Username</label></td>
  <td> <input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="30"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
   <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password"></td>
</tr>

<tr>

   <td><label for="email">Email</label></td>
   <td><input type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="30"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td><input type="submit" value="Register"></td>
</tr>


</form>
</table>
```

It is always a good practice to make any form in either a Table or in a Div.